# Dynamodb scan() using FilterExpression

Tags: python, python-2.7, amazon-dynamodb

First post here on Stack and fairly new to programming with Python and using DynamoDB, but I'm simply trying to run a scan on my table that returns results based on two pre-defined attributes.

---Here is my Python code snippet---

```
shift = "3rd"
date = "2017-06-21"

if shift != "":
    response = table.scan(
        FilterExpression=Attr("Date").eq(date) and Attr("Shift").eq(shift)
    )
```

My DynamoDB has 4 fields.

1. ID
2. Date
3. Shift
4. Safety

[image: DynamoDB Pic]

Now for the issue, upon running I'm getting two table entries returned when I should only be getting the first entry... the one with "No safety issues" based on my scan criteria.

---Here is my DynamoDB return results---

```
[
  {
    "Shift": "3rd",  
    "Safety": "No safety issues",  
    "Date": "2017-06-21",
    "ID": "2"
  }, 
  {
    "Shift": "3rd", 
    "Safety": "Cut Finger", 
    "Date": "2017-06-22", 
    "ID": "4"
  }
]
```

Items Returned:  2

I believe that by applying the FilterExpression with the logical 'and' specified that the scan operation is looking for entries that meet BOTH criteria since I used 'and'.

Could this be because the 'shift' attribute "3rd" is found in both entries? How do I ensure it returns entries based on BOTH criteria being meet and not just giving me results from one attribute type?

I have a feeling this is simple but I've looked at the available documentation at: http://boto3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/services/dynamodb.html#DynamoDB.Table.scan and am still having trouble. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

P.S. I tried to keep the post simple and easy to understand (not including all my program code) however, if additional information is needed I can provide it!

Answer (score 33, accepted):

This is because you used Python's `and` keyword in your expression, instead of the `&` operator.

If `a` and `b` are both considered `True`, `a and b` returns the latter, `b`:

```
>>> 2 and 3
3
```

If any of them is `False`, or if both of them are, the first `False` object is returned:

```
>>> 0 and 3
0
>>> 0 and ''
0
>>>
```

The general rule is, `and` returns the first object that allows it to decide the truthiness of the whole expression.

Python objects are always considered `True` in boolean context. So, your expression:

```
Attr("Date").eq(date) and Attr("Shift").eq(shift)
```

will evaluate as the last `True` object, that is:

```
Attr("Shift").eq(shift)
```

which explains why you only filtered on the shift.

You need to use the `&` operator. It usually means "bitwise and" between integers in Python,  it is redefined for Attr objects to mean what you want: "both conditions".

So you must use the "bitwise and":

```
FilterExpression=Attr("Date").eq(date) & Attr("Shift").eq(shift)
```

According to [the documentation](http://boto3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/guide/dynamodb.html#querying-and-scanning),

> You are also able to chain conditions together using the logical
>   operators: & (and), | (or), and ~ (not).

Comment: Thank you for the explanation! I see now!

Comment: Thanks a lot. You are a legend.

Answer (score 8):

Dynamodb scan() using FilterExpression

For multiple filters, you can use this approach:

```
import boto3
from boto3.dynamodb.conditions import Key, And

filters = dict()
filters['Date'] = "2017-06-21"
filters['Shift'] = "3rd"

response = table.scan(FilterExpression=And(*[(Key(key).eq(value)) for key, value in filters.items()]))
```

Comment: What if you want to filter for any Date before "2017-06-21", how would the code look like?

Comment: Unfortunately, in this specific case this function only supports equality.
A quick way would be: `query = [(Key(key).eq(value)) for key, value in filter.items()][0]` `query = query & Attr("Date").lt('2017-06-21')`  `result = table.scan(FilterExpression=query)`

Comment: This solution worked well for me but when I add a third key/value to the filters dictionary I get an error: ClientError: An error occurred (ValidationException) when calling the Scan operation: Value provided in ExpressionAttributeNames unused in expressions: keys: {#n2}

Answer (score 8):

Using parts from each of the above answers, here's a compact way I was able to get this working:

```py
from functools import reduce
from boto3.dynamodb.conditions import Key, And

response = table.scan(FilterExpression=reduce(And, ([Key(k).eq(v) for k, v in filters.items()])))
```

Allows filtering upon multiple conditions in `filters` as a `dict`. For example:

```
{
    'Status': 'Approved', 
    'SubmittedBy': 'JackCasey'
}
```

Comment: This reduce is used amazing

Answer (score 5):

Expanding on Maxime Paille's answer, this covers the case when only one filter is present vs many.

```
from boto3.dynamodb.conditions import And, Attr
from functools import reduce
from operator import and_

filters = dict()
filters['Date'] = "2017-06-21"
filters['Shift'] = "3rd"

table.scan("my-table", **build_query_params(filters))

def build_query_params(filters):
    query_params = {}
    if len(filters) > 0:
        query_params["FilterExpression"] = add_expressions(filters)

    return query_params

def add_expressions(self, filters: dict):
    if filters:
        conditions = []
        for key, value in filters.items():
            if isinstance(value, str):
                conditions.append(Attr(key).eq(value))
            if isinstance(value, list):
                conditions.append(Attr(key).is_in([v for v in value]))
        return reduce(and_, conditions)
```

Comment: There's a variable mismatch, `expressions.items()` should be `filters.items()`