# Scan DynamoDB with boto3

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

I am currently trying to scan an entire DynamoDB table and looking for specific values under specific attributes. If those values match with what I am looking for, I want my python code to delete the entire DynamoDB item. So far, I currently have:

```
    dynamodb = boto3.resource('dynamodb')
    table = dynamodb.Table('name-of-table-here')
    response = table.scan()
    data = response['Items']
```

I wanted to have something like this:

```
    for item in data:
       if valueOfAttribute == value_being_searched:
          delete DynamoDB item
       else:
          pass
```

Not sure how to go about this. Any suggestions are appreciated, thank you!

Comment: If you can do the filtering as a FilterExpression then you can use a ProjectionExpression to only return the keys. That makes the delete really easy, you just pass in the item you got. I'm not a Python person, so I can't really show you what I mean in Python.

Comment: @JasonWadsworth ah!! thank you! I'm assuming it would be something like this based on what you are saying: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44704443/dynamodb-scan-using-filterexpression

I appreciate the input a lot. I'll check it out and update this thread on how it worked out :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was able to successfully solve this with the FilterExpression as suggested in a previous comment.

Here is what I came up with:

```
    import boto3
    from boto3.dynamodb.conditions import Key

    fe = Key('attribute').eq('value')

    response = table.scan(
    FilterExpression=fe)
    data = response['Items']
```